# shorting resistors in series & tricky NPN circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

If you have 3 resistors in series with 2 ohm each and power supply is 3v.

Each resistor would be 1 volt each.

[image]

What would happen if you short it like the following?

[image]

What would be the voltage of each?

Answer seems to be the top most resistor would have full 3 volts while the other two below it would be zero volts.

This is the tricky circuit:

[image]

When base was not triggered. And current doesn't flow from collector to emitter. The LED turns on.

When base was triggered. And current can flow from collector to emitter. Then just like the 3 resistor analogy, the current won't go to the LED and the LED turns off.

Have you tried this circuit too?  Is this commonly used?

Comment: it's not school work. i'm analyzing a tricky circuit

Comment: see edit for the tricky circuit

Comment: from a GFCI circuit. When the chip is damaged, the red fault light would turn on.

Comment: then yes, it is commonly used in a particular brand of GFCI breakers

Comment: where else is it used? don't other circuits use the same technique too?

Comment: same technique to turn off LED when the base has input. I just want to confirm if that is how it works.

Comment: you really need to think carefully about what you want to ask before posting your questions ..... this is what you wanted to ask, but you asked the beginner electronic question about the resistors instead .... i have a feeling that you already knew the answer to the resistor question ................ no, this technique would not usually be used to turn off an LED ...... usually an LED would be turned off by turning off the current ..... this technique turns off the LED by shorting out the power supply, which draws more current from the power supply

Comment: the question at the end makes this an opinion based question

Comment: But since there is a 1M ohm resistor, then the power supply won't be damaged? and it can work? I don't know the answer to the resistor question. I thought the two below would still get voltage.

Comment: your question that you asked has been answered below by @hs7624. ..... it is the correct answer ... you should accept it .... and stop putting additional questions into the comments

Comment: you mean I must ask new question via new post?

Comment: i mean, stop asking additional questions in comments ..... they have nothing to do with the three resistors..... your original question about the resistors has been answered

Comment: ok. you must be the mod.

Answer (score 1):

The complete voltage will drop across 1st 2Ohm resistor which will be 3V.
Voltage across other resistors will be 0.

Comment: Hi, how about this circuit with a bypass? What would be the voltage of each? https://imageshack.com/a/img923/7343/zYJJ80.jpg  Thanks.

Comment: Hi, here all 2Ohm will be parallel. Hence voltage across all would be 3V.

Comment: Why, when resistors are in parallel, how would the voltage divide among them?

Comment: voltages would be equal in parallel